# Calling a function printMultiples

Tags: python

I need to write a function `printMultiples(lst)` that takes a list of numbers and PRINTS the number if it is a multiple of 8

```py
>>> printMultiples([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

So whenever I run this I don't get any output just a blank line. I'm told I need to call the function `printMultiples`, but I am clueless how to do that.

```py
printMultiples = [(2, 3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
def printMultiples(lst):
    for i in lst[0]:
        if (i%8==0):
          print (i)
```

I should see the number 8 print out but I seem to be missing a step or a line.

Comment: You're overriding the `printMultiples` array with the function name, also you're creating a list with a tuple inside, this may be not what you wan't  just `printMultiples = [2, 3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` would suffice

Comment: Your first line shows how to call the function: `printMultiples([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`.

Comment: Just to be clear: Your question is "How do I call a function?", correct?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: no, the OP's code contains the bug `for i in lst[0]` instead of `for i in lst`

Answer (score 2):

The function is well defined, and it does what you want it to do. The problem is that you are naming a variable with the same name as your function, so it gets overriden, use the following:

```py
multiples = [(2, 3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
def printMultiples(lst):
    for i in lst[0]:
        if (i%8==0):
          print (i)
printMultiples(multiples)
```

**Output:**
8

As @roganjosh has suggested, you can improve your code by following [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

```py
multiples = [(2, 3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]

def print_multiples(lst):
    for number in lst[0]:
        if number % 8 == 0:
            print(number)

print_multiples(multiples)
```

Comment: You could have taken this opportunity to fix the PEP8 issues too, which would go a long way to making the code understandable to the wider Python community. Is `printMultiples` a class or a function? camelCase doesn't feature in almost all of Python.

Comment: @roganjosh, Thanks, I did it, and I mentioned you in the edit. It is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line of code shows how to call the function:

```
>>> printMultiples([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Node that the `>>>` signals that you can anything following it in the Python REPL. If you are saving this in a file, you don't need to type the `>>>`.

The problem with the rest of the code is that you assign a list to the same name that you give to your function. If you want to put the list in a variable, you should give it a different name:

```
multiples = [2, 3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Note that I also removed the parentheses. When you call the function by directly passing the array in, you need parentheses `()` around the brackets `[]`. But when you assign a list to a variable, you don't need the parentheses at all.

Now to call the function with this variable, you put the variable name in parentheses after the function name:

```
printMultiples(multiples)
```

Add this line at the end of your program. Be sure that it is **not** indented.

Answer (score 1):

Others have stated that your list containing the multiples cannot be the same name as your function. Also, why not just store the multiples as list, like this:

```
lst = [2, 3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def printMultiples(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i%8==0:
          print(i)

printMultiples(lst)
```